# Validation of input field with short line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
data['name'] = $("#name").val() != '' ? $("#name").val() : validated == false;
```

if my name input field is not field and validated will be assign to false, but why it doesn't work in above code?

Comment: `validated == false` is a **condition**, not an **assignment**. You probably are trying to do something like that instead: http://jsfiddle.net/ydu1ezow/ , which is basically the same as above, but instead of == you have =. Also, please show more effort when asking a question, I've understood the problem from the code rather than from the explanation.

Comment: Validated is not assigned to false, actually